# How can I get d3-selection-multi in scope for an external js file in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nuxt.js

In my script tag on my vue page I am using:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "d3-selection-multi";
import CreateGrid from "@/assets/javascript/transformations/Grid";
```

In my Grid.js file I make a call using attrs, but when my program runs I get the error: grid.append(...).attrs is not a function

I have also tried adding this to nuxt.config.js:

```
head: {
  script: [
    {
      src: "/js/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js",
    },
  ]
}
```

And I have the js file in static/js, but I still get the same error.

How can I get this to work?